# Is it possible to use jQuery/javascript to place a place a DIV repeatedly every x pixels

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, css, repeat

My problem is this. I have a DIV which replicates an image using CSS3. This Div needs to be repeated at a set interval down one side of the page. I.e. every 200px. Is there a way to for this to be automated. Normally I would use a repeating bgimage but in this case no images are allowed. I also could repeat the div each time but it's a large page that will be updated frequently with more content.

Any ideas would be very much appreciated.

Comment: You said you "replicate the image using css3" and in other sentence you said that no images are allowed. What's the backgound exactly?

Comment: I'm using css3 to produce what appears to be an image. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: @Litek: I'm guessing it's replicate as in 'reproduce using CSS3'.

Comment: the divs must be in position absolute, fixed or in the flow of the page? and does the document height change after page is loaded?

Comment: The doc height stays the same. I have a left bar and an div called .hole that i wish to repeat it every '200px' vertically inside the left bar

Comment: and why can't you put an image? if it's to don't rely on a link you could use data:// with the image base64 encoded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it like this:

document height / element height + 200px = x
place the element X times in to you document.

That's it.

Spoken in jQuery this looks like that:

try it out here: http://jsfiddle.net/aF68z/

```
var repeatMe = function ( $o, space ){
  var oHeight,dHeight, multiplicator, res, html, $parent;

  dHeight = $(document).height(); //height of you document
  oHeight = $o.height(); //height of the element that shoud repeat 
  multiplicator = Math.floor(dHeight / (oHeight + space)); //how many time the element can repeat (including the margin)
  $parent = $o.parent(); //gets the parent that finally will hold all repeating items
  html = $parent.html(); //gets the HTML code of the element that repeats

  /* appending and cloning are very CPU heavy and it makes no sense to do so only for a visual matter, "string" + "string" etc... is very slow if the string becomes long, this is a simple trick how to avoid this: */
  res = [];  
  for (var i = 0; i < multiplicator; ++ i) {
    res.push(html);
  }
  html = res.join("");


  $parent.html(html); //appending the HTML of the all the repeated elements to the parent again.
};

repeatMe( $("div.deco div:eq(0)"),200 );
```

PS: At least try something on your own next time.

Comment: I didn't down vote you, but I'm guessing you way over complicated the problem

Comment: @Abe Petrillo: its the solution that performs best, its generic and its complete. A down-vote is for a answer that is wrong, misleading or offensive, not answers that surpass the excepted scope seam to complicated. Your answer for example is simply wrong because

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.myDiv').append($('.myDiv').clone())
```

and give the div a margin-bottom style of 200px

**EDIT:**
For those complaning that its not a loop and nested Divs

```
for(i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    $('.myDiv').after($('.myDiv').clone().removeClass('myDiv')) 
}
```

Comment: this does it once only, and does not answers the question.

Comment: you could wrap it with `for(var i=1;i<Math.Floor(document.height/(size_of_div+200));i++){ /* ... */ };`

Comment: @enki +1 or you gould read my answers, that does exactly that ;) But cloneing is very slow, you sould not clone, especially if the page is very long.

Comment: `document.height` is not so nice, `$(document).height()` should be better for compatibility

Comment: Wrapped this in a for loop and it worked fine, thank you for your help

Comment: @tcnarss : this appends a clone of .myDiv to it self, what is gonna end in some nasty nesting.

Comment: @meo it's working okay at the moment(performance), i may have to revisit this if the page expands greatly. I did try your method but couldn't get it running, I think jsfiddle may be on the blink as it took forever to load, thank you anyway.

Comment: @meo I changed the first .myDiv to the name of my left bar (.left-holes if ya interested) and the second myDiv to the name of.. my div :)

Comment: @tcnarss: all you need to do is to place: `<div class="deco"><div></div></div>` in you HTML and it will work (the nested div is gonna be the DIV that repeats)

Comment: @meo I'll give it a try and check the perfomance of both. thanks again

Comment: @tcnarss let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1885/discussion-between-meo-and-tcnarss)

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
.yourClass{
       width:200px;
       height:yourHeightValue;
}
.imgClass{
       text-align:center;
}
```

and add as many `<div class="yourClass"><img class="imgClass" src="..."/></div>` as you need.

Comment: This doesn't really fit with the _"Normally I would use a repeating bgimage but in this case no images are allowed"_ bit of the question...

Comment: You've edited it, but this doesn't really fit with the _"no images are allowed"_ bit of the question...

Comment: You want to replicate an image and "no images are allowed"? Good luck!

Comment: **Replicate**: _Make an exact copy of; reproduce_.  Have a look at [this link](http://www.romancortes.com/blog/homer-css/) for a replication of Homer Simpson using pure CSS :)

Comment: I had a look on your link. There is no image which are replicated. They are using background color to a multiple div to produce an "image effect".

Comment: that's what he says, it's not a replication of an image but a replication of a reproduction ( using background-color and css3 ) of an image

Comment: Precisely - they've taken an image of Homer Simpson and replicated it using CSS.

Comment: First sentence of the problem: "My problem is this. I have a DIV which replicates an image using CSS3." so he said "an image is replicated using CSS3" not "there is a replication of a reproduction".

Comment: Let's not get into a discussion about reproduction, that's a different subject entirely... ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to repaeat divs vertically you could do:

```
.yourClass{
       height:200px;
       width:whatyouwant;
}

var numberOfDivs = 8;//chose the number you want or calculate it
var div = $('<div>', {class: 'yourClass'});//create your div
for (i=0; i < numberOfDivs ; i++){
     $('.leftSidebar').append(div);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am not misundestanding your question, this may be helpful.

```
var times = 10;
var elementToRepeat = $('.myDiv'); 
var lastElement = elementToRepeat;
for(var i = 0 ; i < times ; times++){
   var newElement = elementToRepeat.clone();
   lastElement.after(newElement);
   lastElement = newElement;
}
```

Also, set a margin bottom to the div's class, so that they have the desired separation.

Comment: now try `times = 1000` and have fun :) this is gonna be slow.